# SIP UPDATE with Supported: timer

Tags: sip

I have error scenario in SIP flow, UAC doesn't support refresh session, UAS sends "Supported: timer", but anyway the UAC doesn't support timer, the refresh UPDATE is sent from B side. A side doesn't respond on this UPDATEs(32s retransmission from B side) and then call is disconnected on BYE. In dialog there is Allow:  UPDATE from UAC, so UAC should recognize the SIP message, but what is the correct behavior?
thanks.

Ignore this message or respond with some 4xx/5xx messages?

Answer (score 1):

Session Timer functionality is described in [RFC4028](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4028). This SIP extension has the property that it works even when only one UA in a dialog supports it. In your case only the UAS; therefore the UAS becomes the refresher and sends the UPDATE request to the UAC. This is all as expected.

The problem here is the fact that the UAC doesn't respond to the received UPDATE request, even though it included the method in the Allow header. You must try to figure out why the UAC doesn't respond at all. It should always return a (final) response.